# JMenuBar at the top of BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

This is how it looks contained in a `BorderLayout`:

[image: jmenubar borderlayout]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: jmenubar null layout]

As you can see it's not at the top of the frame. Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: What is the difference except L&F?

Comment: It's Windows L&F in both. Can't you see that in the first picture my JMenuBar isn't at the top? There's a small space.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't set `JMenuBar` by using `BorderLayout` at all. Instead of that, simply call [setJMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar%28javax.swing.JMenuBar%29) method from your `JFrame` instance.